# How to detect homographic text, unicode spoofing with node.js

Tags: node.js, unicode, punycode

Users can get their own subsites on ours, so that www.example.com/subsite/gary would then be a specific users subsite.

However I am worried about the possibility of homographic / unicode spoofing attacks, where a malicious user creates an account with a different username but with unicode characters that will appear the same to others, and in that way can pass around a link purporting to be gary when it is in fact someone else.

The only solution I've seen to this that looks mature is UCAPI http://www.casaba.com/products/UCAPI/ but I would prefer not to use it, I would like to have something that works with node.js. (to the extent that I would rather implement myself if need be)

has anyone an example where they can check for these kinds of homographic / spoofing attacks with node.js?

Comment: Wait long enough and someone will implement it for you - https://www.npmjs.com/package/homoglyph-search

Answer (score 0):

You could try using [Unicode normalization with `String.prototype.normalize`](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode#accounting-for-lookalikes) which is available in Node.js v0.12, but I doubt that takes care of every possible attack vector.

**Use [UCAPI](http://www.casaba.com/products/UCAPI/)** — it’s made for your exact use case.